# Python Selenium webdriver get issue

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I know there is an issue with downloading files.

But do you know on a solution for an issue like that:

When you opening this url (which is google plus's search)
https://plus.google.com/complete/search?client=gp-suggest-mixed&hl=iw&gs_rn=18&gs_ri=gp-suggest-mixed&tok=Dn6zK1ETV-QV-V3N5h66wg&dtok=1AFrce83BcykhVp0_Xgb1Wxip8QYw&cp=17&gs_id=6p&q=test@gmail.com&xhr=t

It's downloading the result.

When I'm trying to use `web_driver.get(https://plus.google.com/complete/search?client=gp-suggest-mixed&hl=iw&gs_rn=18&gs_ri=gp-suggest-mixed&tok=Dn6zK1ETV-QV-V3N5h66wg&dtok=1AFrce83BcykhVp0_Xgb1Wxip8QYw&cp=17&gs_id=6p&q=test@gmail.com&xhr=t)`

I'm not getting anything. I'm using PhantomJS.

Any ideas for how getting the data using Phantom and Selenium?

Comment: Which version of PhantomJS do you use? I don't mean the Java webdriver library.

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.1